# Custom authorization i asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a project which uses both Web Api and MVC. The authentication is handled by FormsAuthentication, which creates a cookie containing some data regarding the user.

I have extended System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute and added it to every MVC controller. What it does is extend AuthorizeCore and check to content of the cookie, which is my own extension of IPrinciple, for wether the user currently has limited access.

I would like to do a similar check for calls to my Web Api, so i have made an extension for System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute which overrides the IsAuthorized method.
In this method i would like to make the same check as for the controller, but i don't know how to get the information from the cookie or if this is even the proper way to do this.

Comment: There's no need to touch the auth cookie! Let it be.

Answer (score 0):

In general using cookie authentication in web api is not recommended.
The reason is that cookies are handled well only in browsers The whole concept of web api is to allow other clients (native clients, java script ...) to use it as well.

If you sure that your server is going to be accessed from browser only maybe you should move your api actions to MVC project (it could return json / xml as well). This way you will not have to deal with those kind of issues.

For web api I would recommend using token based authentication